# "participant" is not clickable. Why?

Tags: support

What does it mean that the author Summon's glyph/ID in question

- [Windows Server 2008 - Connecting to 127.0.0.1](https://serverfault.com/questions/170476/windows-server-2008-connecting-to-127-0-0-1)

is not clickable as of the other participants?

Comment: The question was migrated from stackoverflow, does that point you in the right direction?

Comment: The question was migrated, because he posted something on SO that was not appropriate for it. He can associate the accounts whenever he likes and begin gaining rep here for it.

Answer (score 4):

It is because the question was transferred from another of the trilogy of sites, and that user either does not have an account on the site that it was transferred to or they have not associated their account. It is essentially "orphaned" until the accounts are associated.

Answer (score 2):

This means he was not registered on Server Fault when he posted the question.